# duplicate ID in aspx c# when sending emails

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Im creating a tracking system in aspx c# and I want the user to submit a ticket and it'll assign it an ID and send the email.

I got everything to work but the problem is if two or more users are on the same page it'll assign them the same ID when they send the email (#150 and #150). However in Sql, it would be (#150 and #151).

aspx.cs page (Im getting the current ID from SQL)

```
id.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["id"].ToString();
```

Then I'm incrementing it by 1 (to send the email) Because I dont want the current users that's sending the request to have an old ID.

```
id = id + 1;
```

Note that this works perfectly if only one users is on the page submitting the request. 
Can someone get a work around this? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you fetch the actual ID from your database?

Comment: Agree with @DavidHedlund, Before sending the email grab the Max(ID) and use that value instead

Comment: `@Identity` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Yes, certainly `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or similar. `MAX(ID)` is subject to the same race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the logged-in user's id on the url to handle a user's session and also set the email ID (check example below):

`.aspx?user_id=150&email_id=150`

Then you need to use the appropriate user's session that opens your webpage as shown below to get the appropriate ID as an email ID.

`id.Text = Session[user_id].ToString();`

For that reason when both users are logged in simultaneously you only get the same id for both. You probably have a static site that handles only one session per user.